# Snap victim memorial reference in Avengers: Endgame

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* when Ant-man visits memorial stones, he went through lots of names to go through. But as per the nature of Marvel films, it seems like these names can't be all random.

Is any of those names refer to any real or fictional Marvel-related character/person?

Comment: This comment is pretty unrelated, but a friend of mine argued that it can't have been random, "because they were all alphabetically ordered". In his defense, he followed that up with "oh wait, never mind".

Comment: Related: [Were there two appearances of Stan Lee?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211046/98028) on SFF.

Comment: @Jenayah noticed that one, related but quite different

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is one reference we can list.

In the memorial, there is a name Roberto da Costa aka Sunspot. This mutant is going to be in an upcoming film, The New Mutants. This refers to the upcoming merge of X-Men and current MCU. I don't have a screenshot at the moment.

From [Bookmyshow article](https://in.bookmyshow.com/entertainment/movies/english/avengers-endgame-easter-eggs/),

> MCU has always avoided referencing X-Men which might have been due to the fact that the rights were owned by Fox. Now that the Disney-Fox merger is over, we can expect to see more X-Men references, with Avengers: Endgame being the first of many. After Ant-Man returns from the quantum realm five years later, he comes across the Vanishing Memorial that has been set up with names of everyone who had been dusted and scans through them. **One of the names is Roberto da Costa aka Sunspot, a mutant who is associated with The New Mutants and X-Force. He is confirmed to be in the New Mutants film coming this August and might be in the upcoming X-Force film with Deadpool too.**

Comment: On the other hand, that's not an unusual name :)

Comment: Is that the only one? I would be surprised if there weren't like a dozen name references there

Comment: Never mind there've already been two X-Men featured prominently in MCU movies (Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch), though of course they've never been actually _called_ X-Men.  I wonder if they'll retroactively change that now...